# Bulk inserting in database blocking UI?

Tags: android, sqlite, user-interface

In my app, I'm getting a response from the server and inserting the values that I get from the server response in the database. Following is my code:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO "+ tableName +" VALUES (?,?,?,?);";
    DatabaseHandler dbHandler = new DatabaseHandler(context);
     final SQLiteDatabase db = dbHandler.getWritableDatabase();
        final SQLiteStatement statement = db.compileStatement(sql);
        db.beginTransaction();
        try {

                statement.clearBindings();

                statement.bindString(2, id);
                statement.bindString(3, type);
                statement.bindString(4, value);

                statement.executeInsert();

            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        } finally {
            db.endTransaction();
        }

        db.close();
```

It is inserting fast in my database but my UI screen is getting freezed. I tried calling my inserting code in an AsyncTask but then the inserting is taking a very long time. Could you please let me know how can I prevent my UI from getting blocked and also preventing the inserting from taking a very long time?

Thank you.

Comment: "I tried calling my inserting code in an AsyncTask but then the inserting is taking a very long time" It should take no longer than it takes blocking your UI.

Comment: there is only 1 insert done here. I doubt it is very long.

Comment: If you are doing one transaction per insert, of course it will be very slow. Move the `db.beginTransaction();` and other stuff out of the inner loop and around the loop that inserts the data.

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe that insertion will be taking too long using AsyncTask,but if it is taking then **even then it is a better approach then what you are trying to achieve**..That is "*Performing Insert in database for large amount of data on the UI thread*".

- Your application may get crashed if you will perform this long running task on the UI thread.
- That's why the `AsyncTask`s were made for,to take away load from the `UI` thread.
- You can try an alternative of starting a **IntentService** if you are so much annoyed with the time taken by the device to perform insertion.It will keep on doing its work at the back end while you can perform other tasks .

Comment: Using Service doesn't mean you won't be blocking UI. By default Service instance runs on UI thread.